# Nginx - PHP FPM how to see which php script is running

Tags: php, nginx

I use NGINX and PHP FPM, sometimes there are a lot of php-fpm processes and the website become unaccessable.

i use top at console and get this :

```
9214 apache    20   0  455740  11720   2180 R  2.3  1.2   0:59.30 php-fpm
9154 apache    20   0  456188  13744   2316 R  2.0  1.4   1:00.20 php-fpm
9169 apache    20   0  456200  10876   2212 R  2.0  1.1   0:59.52 php-fpm
9173 apache    20   0  456084  10396   2132 R  2.0  1.0   0:59.83 php-fpm
9178 apache    20   0  445940  14968   2180 R  2.0  1.5   1:01.91 php-fpm
9190 apache    20   0  456272  10684   2168 R  2.0  1.0   0:59.26 php-fpm
9191 apache    20   0  456164  12136   2288 R  2.0  1.2   0:58.98 php-fpm
9195 apache    20   0  455868  10404   2160 R  2.0  1.0   0:59.34 php-fpm
9208 apache    20   0  456064  17548   2184 R  2.0  1.7   0:59.07 php-fpm
9232 apache    20   0  455952  16728   2188 R  2.0  1.6   0:58.90 php-fpm
9235 apache    20   0  456088  16212   2184 R  2.0  1.6   0:59.02 php-fpm
9237 apache    20   0  456344  10484   2188 R  2.0  1.0   0:58.76 php-fpm
27727 apache    20   0  460308  10776   2088 R  2.0  1.1   9:46.56 php-fpm
27733 apache    20   0  460052  11012   2144 R  2.0  1.1   9:57.32 php-fpm
32321 apache    20   0  460020  16904   2536 R  2.0  1.7   6:33.11 php-fpm
```

How can i know, which php script caused that, thank you

Comment: Take a look at the log file?

Comment: Nginx yet it says apache...? wot?

Comment: @henrikstroem
didn't know which php script is running, which log shows that?

Comment: @Darren
i don't know why it said apache, i'm using nginx and php-fpm

Comment: @ostrichegret Your config file should have entries for the log files - they are probably somewhere in `/var/log/` depending on the distribution you are using.